# how to shutdown thread whose work has completed in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Lets take example #
i m opening thread 300 per second and memory usage become very high
but what i want is each thread must release memory
and should be disapper from my system after its work finished.

is it possile  ? jmeter

I tried to check memory but not sure #
i tried to checck graph where i can check threads but i cant see they shut down their own.

## what  i tried

i tried loop and graph to see is after completion of work of thread is disapper but it is not

Answer (score 0):

The memory used by thread will "disappear" upon next [garbage collection](https://stackify.com/what-is-java-garbage-collection/) cycle

You can force full GC using suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and the following line of code:

```
System.gc()
```

or 3rd-party solutions like [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/):

[image]

however given you're short on memory you might get false-negative test results so I would rather suggest checking if you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if yes consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) Mode as if JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough you won't be able to conduct the necessary load.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is an open source tool and has memory leakage problems. I would recommend to use JMeter for optimized load and performance testing.

1. Configure JMeter heap size in JMeter properties file.
2. Use a mix of thread group and loops for better simulation of load.
3. Use GUI mode and listeners only for debugging your tests.
4. Use CLI / Command system for execution of tests and write your test results in file which you can later review in any of the listeners.
5. For massive loads you can use [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html).
6. Also, take a look on [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).